# Why does CPU=8 in Intel Core i9-12900K have the fastest access to all other cores?

Tags: performance, cpu, intel, cpu-architecture

This is the [original tests](https://github.com/nviennot/core-to-core-latency). The [figure](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/297060/190930511-337ef53e-52c0-4350-9022-485689b7f242.png) shows that CPU=8 in Intel Core i9-12900K has the fastest access to all other cores.

Therefore, I am wondering what makes it happen.

Besides, I am also curious about the yellow part in the same figure. Why the core-to-core latency in the same E-core cluster is larger than in the different clusters?

Comment: Makes me wonder if it's a fluke of which L3 slice contained the cache line for the shared variable in that test run.  Unless this is consistent across runs (different physical address of the shared var) and across with different shared vars between different pairs of cores.  Otherwise maybe something about ring bus geometry, but I thought it was bidirectional so any two adjacent pairs could talk to each other fast.  Or to the L3 slice containing the memory they're accessing, since that's what really happens AFAIK.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have looked up the data of i9-12900k in the repository. It seems that the latency is tested from core A to core B, but there is no reverse process. So I agree with you that the variable is stored in the home slice of core 8. The same thing happens to the E-cluster that the variable is stored in the home slice of E-cluster 2.